# Laravel stuck in Authentication loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am stuck in an authentication loop, and for the life of me cannot understand why.

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
    //return 'Hello ' . Auth::user()->first_name . '!';
});

Route::get('/login', function() {
    return View::make('login'); 
});

Route::post('/login', function() {

    // @TODO: Validate the login details!

    Auth::attempt(array(
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
        ));

    return Redirect::to('/');
});


Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {

    Route::get('/home', function()
    {
        //return View::make('hello');
        return 'Hello ' . Auth::user()->first_name . '!';
    });


    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | API Route Handlers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The API Routes.
    |
    */

    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function() {

        Route::resource('events', 'EventsController');

    });

});
```

**Here is the sequence of events:**

I go to `localhost:8000/home` it works and redirects me to `/login`.

I then move on to log in.

It redirects me to the `/` if I then go to `/home` it still takes me to `/login`

**Ideal case:**

Go to `/home` only to be redirected to `/login`

I log in then.

It redirects me to `/`

I can then move freely between `/` and `/home` without the worry of logging in.

**EDIT 1**

```
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');

            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('id_number')->unique();

            $table->enum('user_type', array('option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3'));

            $table->rememberToken();

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the user never gets logged in. Can you check the return value of `Auth::attempt`? (it should be `true`)

Comment: What does Auth::attempt() return? You're not checking if it actually succeeds or not

Comment: @lukasgeiter @Damien Prisy `dd(Auth::attempt()) == bool(false)`

Comment: That means either the input you get is wrong or there's a problem with the db tabel / model. Can you please post the `User` model and the structure of the `users` table? (Also, is the password in your db a hash?)

Comment: @lukasgeiter -- Yes. The `password` in the `users` table is a hash.  I do not have a `User` model at the moment. Is one needed? The structure to the `users` table is also being edited in now.

Comment: It depends. If you have the default `app/config/auth.php` you need one. (but the default Laravel installation also comes with a [User](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/models/User.php) model) Please check if "driver" in `app/config/auth.php` is set to `eloquent` or `database`

Comment: @lukasgeiter -- The `User` Model is there (generated one) and my `driver` is set to `eloquent` in `app/config/auth.php`

Comment: Ok. Can you check that the input (`input` and `password`) is right?

Comment: @lukasgeiter -- It is fixed. Ill update my OP with the new fixed code. All I basically did was `$valid = Auth::attempt();` then I had `if ($valid) { return Redirect::to('/home'); } else { return Redirect::to('/'); }`

Comment: Alright. Please [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) instead of editing the post. This clearly communicates that the problem has been solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it - The problem was that `Auth::attempt()`'s value wasn't being set.

Here is my new updated version of the code.

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
    //return 'Hello ' . Auth::user()->first_name . '!';
});

Route::get('/login', function() {
    return View::make('login'); 
});

Route::post('/login', function() {

    // @TODO: Validate the login details!

    $valid = Auth::attempt(array(
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
        ));

    if ($valid)
    {
        return Redirect::to('/home');
    } 
    else 
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }

});


Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {

    Route::get('/home', function()
    {
        //return View::make('hello');
        return 'Hello ' . Auth::user()->first_name . '!';
    });


    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | API Route Handlers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The API Routes.
    |
    */

    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1'), function() {

        Route::resource('events', 'EventsController');

    });

});
```